# https://language.cognitive.azure.com/clu/projects - get *A server error occurred. Please refresh the page...* every time when creating new project

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am new to Cognitive Services Language Studio and I'm a novice at best with Azure. I was trying to set up LUIS but the site said it was being discontinued and to use CLU instead. I have an Azure account with a new language resource group setup. It's all showing up in the CLU create new project form correctly. However, when I hit CREATE from the second page of the project creation modal I get the error message "UNKNOWN [current time] A server error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again."

Is this an Azure server issue or bug or is there something that I can do on my end to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

I filled out the Create New Project modal and and when I pressed Create I got the above error. Every single time. It is accessing my Azure correctly including the language resource. Everything that has an asterisk next to it is filled out or correctly selected. I don't know if it's because it's a new Azure feature and it's still buggy, or maybe there's late night maintenance, or is there something I can fix on my end and the error message just isn't giving me that information.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create a project right now, I am in S0 tier and southcentralus region. Please share your region so that I can check with your region as well. I don't see any bug in the backend as well.
[image]